# Why is a link (anchor element) within an li element removed when text is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am experiencing strange behavior with jQuery 2.1.3. When I replace text in an anchor element within a list, the anchor is removed. I suspect it has something to do with my selector, but I do not understand why.

**selector:**

```
$("ul li:nth-child(2) a, ul li")
```

This [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/onhyqz1a/4/) shows my code and demonstrates the odd behavior.

Comment: The call to `.text()` replaces _all_ content of the `li`, including the anchors.

Comment: Here's a start, try replacing `$(this).text("deux");` with `$(this).children().text("deux");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is a [fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/onhyqz1a/5/).

Please, note that the selector was changed:

```
$("ul li:nth-child(2) a, ul li:not(:nth-child(2))")
```

The problem is that your original selector

```
$("ul li:nth-child(2) a, ul li")
```

replaces all li tags as specified by the second part of the selector `ul li` no matter what is inside of the `li`.

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function(e) {
    var araEnglish = new Array( 'one', 'two', 'three' ),
        araFrench = new Array( 'un', 'deux', 'trois' ),
        $thisTxt = $(this).text().trim();
    $("ul li:nth-child(2) a, ul li:not(:nth-child(2))").each(function(i) {
        if ($thisTxt == 'To French') txt = $(this).text(araFrench[i]);
        else txt = $(this).text(araEnglish[i]);
    });
    $(this).text($thisTxt == 'To French' ? 'To Anglais' : 'To French');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li><a href="*">two</a></li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
<br/>
<button>To French

</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

Because you're selecting the `<li>` and the `<a>` tag is a child tag, so when you call `.text(...)` that `<a>` tag is overwitten.

```js
$(function() {
 $(document).on('click', '#translate', function(e) {
  var txt,
   araEnglish = new Array( 'one', 'two', 'three' ),
   araFrench = new Array( 'un', 'deux', 'trois' );
  if ($(this).text() == 'To French') {
   $(this).text('To Anglais');
   $('#lstCount li').each(function(i) {
    txt = araFrench[i];
    if ($(this).children().length) $(this).find('*:last-child').text(txt);
    else $(this).text(txt);
   });
  }
  else {
   $(this).text('To French');
   $('#lstCount li').each(function(i) {
    txt = araEnglish[i];
    if ($(this).children().length) $(this).find('*:last-child').text(txt);
    else $(this).text(txt);
   });
  }
 });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="lstCount">
  <li>one</li>
  <li><a href="*">two</a></li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
<br/>
<button id="translate">To French</button>
```

Comment: @rontornambe See *all* of the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

According to your selector, you are replacing the text in `<li>` elements *and* `<a>` elements. When you replace text in all `<li>` elements, their child `<a>` elements are obliterated.

I suggest adding `:not:has(a)` to your selector, so you select all `<li>` elements that don't contain an `<a>`.

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").on("click",
    function() {
      $("ul li a, ul li:not(:has(a))").each(
        function(index) {
          switch (index) {
            case 0:
              $(this).text("un");
              break;
            case 1:
              $(this).text("deux");
              break;
            default:
              $(this).text("trois");
              break;
          }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
<br/>
<button>To French</button>
```

See:
[:has() selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) - contains at least one element that matches the specified selector.
[:not() selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) - does not match the given selector.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for a correct solution but Anton got there first. What is the link to the site you used to illustrate your answer?

Comment: Sorry, which link are you looking for?

Comment: The one that with the buttons (Run code snippet...).

Comment: That's a [stack snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). They run directly from the body of a post :D